# Amcharts category axis to show date for empty data as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, amcharts

I am making a chart on fruits eaten in a day, which is working fine in the below example.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "hideCredits": true,
  "fixedColumnWidth": '10px',

  "legend": {
    "horizontalGap": 10,
    "maxColumns": 1,
    "position": "right",
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10
  },
  "dataProvider": [{
      "creationDate": "04/09/18",
      "Banana": 1,
      "Apple": 13,
      "Grapes": 24
    },

    {
      "creationDate": "06/09/18",
      "Banana": 10,
      "Apple": 13,
      "Grapes": 24
    },

    {
      "creationDate": "08/09/18",
      "Banana": 11,
      "Apple": 13,
      "Grapes": 24
    },
    {
      "creationDate": "09/09/18",
      "Banana": 1,
      "Apple": 50,
      "Grapes": 24
    },
  ],

  //"gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,

  "valueAxes": [{
    "stackType": "regular",
    "axisAlpha": 0.3,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "minimum": 0,
    "maximum": 50,
    "gridCount": 1

  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillColors": "#47b012",
    "lineColor": "#47b012",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Grapes Eaten",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "Grapes",
    "fixedColumnWidth": 25
  }, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillColors": "#fff138",
    "lineColor": "#fff138",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Banana Eaten",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "Banana",
    "fixedColumnWidth": 25
  }, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillColors": "#dd111b",
    "lineColor": "#dd111b",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Apples Eaten",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "Apple",
    "fixedColumnWidth": 25
  }],
  "categoryField": "creationDate",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "labelRotation": 80,
  },
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

**But what I need is to show the data for the day when no fruit is eaten like in the screenshot below.**
[image]

The dates **05-09-2018 and 07-09-2018** data is not in the `dataprovider` field, so I want it to automatically populate in the graph .

Comment: Pretty sure AmCharts will only populate the chart with the values provided, so what you will have to do is add those dates in your dataProvider and set their values to 0

Comment: I know that @SmokeyDawson but is there any method or function that can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently have a regular Category axis which treats dates as strings (categories).

If you want a real date scale, you need to make it a date-base category axis by setting [`parseDates: true`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#parseDates) in `categoryAxis`.

That won't be enough, though.

Since you have your dates as non-standard date format, you will need to instruct amCharts how to parse them. That's where [`dataDateFormat`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#dataDateFormat) setting comes in:

```
dataDateFormat: "DD/MM/YYYY"
```

Finally, labels follow different rules on a date-based axis. So we'll need to make some adjustments to code so that all of them are displayed:

```
"categoryAxis": {
  // ...
  "autoGridCount": false,
  "gridCount": 20
},
```

Here's your chart:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "hideCredits": true,
  "fixedColumnWidth": '10px',
  "dataDateFormat": "DD/MM/YYYY",

  "legend": {
    "horizontalGap": 10,
    "maxColumns": 1,
    "position": "right",
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10
  },
  "dataProvider": [{
      "creationDate": "04/09/18",
      "Banana": 1,
      "Apple": 13,
      "Grapes": 24
    },

    {
      "creationDate": "06/09/18",
      "Banana": 10,
      "Apple": 13,
      "Grapes": 24
    },

    {
      "creationDate": "08/09/18",
      "Banana": 11,
      "Apple": 13,
      "Grapes": 24
    },
    {
      "creationDate": "09/09/18",
      "Banana": 1,
      "Apple": 50,
      "Grapes": 24
    },
  ],

  //"gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,

  "valueAxes": [{
    "stackType": "regular",
    "axisAlpha": 0.3,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "minimum": 0,
    "maximum": 50,
    "gridCount": 1

  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillColors": "#47b012",
    "lineColor": "#47b012",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Grapes Eaten",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "Grapes",
    "fixedColumnWidth": 25
  }, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillColors": "#fff138",
    "lineColor": "#fff138",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Banana Eaten",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "Banana",
    "fixedColumnWidth": 25
  }, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillColors": "#dd111b",
    "lineColor": "#dd111b",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Apples Eaten",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "Apple",
    "fixedColumnWidth": 25
  }],
  "categoryField": "creationDate",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "labelRotation": 80,
    "parseDates": true,
    "autoGridCount": false,
    "gridCount": 20
  },
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```